# Spring AMQP Transactional Processing and Retry

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying the Srpring AMQP features regarding transactional message processing.

I have the following setup - I have a message consumer that is annotated as `@Transactional`

```
@Transactional
    public void handleMessage(EventPayload event) {
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(event.getName());

        Shop savedShop = shopService.create(shop);

        log.info("Created shop {} from event {}", shop, event);
    }
```

In `shopService.create` I save the shop and send another message about the creation:

```
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED)
@Component
public class ShopService {

   ...

    public Shop create(Shop shop) {
        eventPublisher.publish(new EventPayload(shop.getName()));
        return shopRepository.save(shop);
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the following - the message sent in the `create` method should just go to the broker if the database action succeeded. If it fails the message is not sent and the received message is rolled back.

I also have a Retry configured - so I expect each message to be retried 3 times before it is rejected:

```
@Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryOperationsInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000)
                .build();
    }
```

I am observing the following behaviour:

When I configure the container as follows the message is retried 3 times but every time the message in `shopService.create` is sent to the broker:

```
@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(testEventSubscriberQueue().getName());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[]{retryOperationsInterceptor()});
        return container;
    }
```

So I tried passing the `PlatformTransactionManager` to the container -

```
@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter,
                                                            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(testEventSubscriberQueue().getName());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[]{retryOperationsInterceptor()});
        return container;
    }
```

Now the message sent in `shopService.create` is only send to the broker if the database transaction succeeded - which is what I want - but the message is retried indefinitely now - and not discarded after 3 retires as configured. But it seems that the backOff settings are applied - so there is some time between the retries.

The setup described does not really make sense from a business point of view - I am trying to understand and evaluate the transaction capabilities.

I am use spring-amqp 1.5.1.RELEASE

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I just tried using a `StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor` instead of a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` using this `@Bean
    public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor retryOperationsInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000)
                .build();
    }` - This gives me the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirements, an `@RabbitListener` annotated with `@Transactional`, I wanted retry with backoff. It works even stateless with the following config:

```
   @Bean
   public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryOperationsInterceptor( ) {
      return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .maxAttempts( 3 )
            .recoverer( new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer() )
            .backOffOptions(1000, 2, 10000)
            .build();
   }

   @Bean
   public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter( ObjectMapper objectMapper ) {
      Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter( objectMapper );
      jackson2JsonMessageConverter.setCreateMessageIds( true );
      return jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
   }      

   @Bean
   SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory  rabbitListenerContainerFactory( ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                                                   Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter) {
      SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory  container = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory ();
      container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

      container.setChannelTransacted(true);
      container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);

      container.setAdviceChain( retryOperationsInterceptor() );

      container.setMessageConverter( converter );
      return container;
   }
```

To use `stateless()`, using `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` was important because otherwise the retry will work but the consumer will then by default put the message back on the queue. Then the consumer will retrieve it again, applying the retry policy and then putting it back on the queue infinitely.